# Subir archivos a Amazon s3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, amazon-s3

Estimados, tengo un proyecto web que estoy desarrollando con tecnologías Microsoft. El proyecto en sí tiene varios tipos de proyectos, wcf, MVC, entre otros.

Lo que necesito hacer es poder subir archivos (pueden ser imagenes, documentos y distintos tipode de documentos en si .doc, .xls, etc, por supuesto haciendo las respectivas validaciones de tamaño).

El tema es que he leido harta documentación al respecto, sin embargo, me gustaría poder contar con un ejemplo de alguien que haya realizado esta azaña.

En concreto es, tener el ejemplo de la configuración de conexión a **Amazon S3** y un ejemplo en el que se guarde un archivo en dicho repositorio. De antemano agradezco vuestra cooperación. Saludos comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, no he hecho nada en .net ni menos en WCF relacionado con AWS, pero lo básico, es primero, tener obviamente instalado el SDK de AWS para .Net,  configurar las credenciales de acceso al bucket el cual está explicado en http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html y usarlas luego con la instancia del cliente de S3:

```
try {
    /// crear la solicitud para subir el archivo
    /// recibe 3 parámetros: 
    /// 1. BucketName: el nombre del bucket
    /// 2. Key: el nombre del archivo, es como se quiere llamar, incluso con ruta relativa. Ejemplo: directorio/archivo.txt
    /// 3. FilePath: ruta física del archivo a subir
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        FilePath = filePath
    };
    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request); 
} 
catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
{
    if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
      (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
      ||
      amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
        Console.WriteLine("For service sign up go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Por cierto, el tamaño del archivo no interesa mucho desde que se tenga una buena conexión, aunque obviamente no se deberían tener archivos de más de 50MB de Office (EMO) ya que el abrirlos sería tortuoso.